# How to understand Proverbs 6:16-19 in light of Psalm 51:5 and 58:3

Tags: psalms, proverbs, sin

In Proverbs 6, the writer lists 7 things that God hates.

> There are six things that the Lord hates, seven that are an abomination to him: haughty eyes, a lying tongue, and hands that shed **innocent** blood,
> a heart that devises wicked plans, feet that make haste to run to evil, a false witness who breathes out lies, and one who sows discord among brothers. - Proverbs 6:16-19 ESV

I don't think there is a contradiction, but it seems that there is a tension when compared to Psalm 51:5 and 58:3

> Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity, and in sin did my mother conceive me. - Psalm 51:5 ESV
>
> The wicked are estranged from the womb; they go astray from birth, speaking lies. - Psalm 58:3 ESV

Who are the innocent mentioned in the proverb if no one is innocent by the verses in the Psalms?

I also think Jesus' words could be considered here also when talking about little children.

> but whoever **causes** one of these **little ones** who believe in me **to sin**, it would be better for him to have a great millstone fastened around his neck and to be drowned in the depth of the sea. - Matthew 18:6

Are these little children an example of the innocent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be careful to keep two things clearly separate.  As pointed out in Ps 51:5 and 58:3 (we could also add Rom 3:10-18, 22-25) "all have sinned" and so all are guilty before God.

HOWEVER, the fact that all have sinned does not make any one person guilty of a crime they have not committed.  Thus, there is a difference between general human depravity and sinfulness (as per Ps 51:5, 58:3;Rom 3:10-18, 22-25) and civil crimes.

FURTHER, God ONLY is the judge of spiritual sinfulness and arranging our salvation, while civil governments are responsible for keeping civil order as Paul is at pains to point out in Rom 13:1-7.  See also Matt 22:15-22, Mark 12:13-17, Luke 20:20-26, Titus 3:1, 1 Peter 2:13-17.

Therefore, while we are all sinners and guilty before God, we are not guilty of civil crimes unless we have actually committed those crimes.  Prov 6:16-19 is discussing civil affairs not general human sinfulness.  "Shedding innocent blood" I take to mean executing someone for a crime they did not commit, or, simply murdering a person and thus breaking the 6th commandment.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had come to a similar conclusion soon after posting this but I wanted to leave it open. Do you think the shedding of innocent blood in Proverbs could also refer to the unborn or is that a stretch?

Comment: I will betray my bias by answering "yes" but that does not mean that all abortion is wrong, although the vast number are definitely wrong!  There are rare cases where abortion is unavoidable but these are very rare compared to the huge numbers of unborn babies killed for no good reason.

Comment: The Lord spoke to Moses, saying, “Say to the people of Israel, Any one of the people of Israel or of the strangers who sojourn in Israel who gives any of his children to Molech shall surely be put to death. The people of the land shall stone him with stones. I myself will set my face against that man and will cut him off from among his people, because he has given one of his children to Molech, to make my sanctuary unclean and to profane my holy name.

Comment: And if the people of the land do at all close their eyes to that man when he gives one of his children to Molech, and do not put him to death, then I will set my face against that man and against his clan and will cut them off from among their people, him and all who follow him in whoring after Molech” (Leviticus 20:1–5).

Comment: The reason murder is wrong, besides God's command not to, is because it violates the image of God in another human. The only difference when it comes to abortion is location, and stage of development. You cannot consistently argue that we should follow the 6th commandment and at the same time not decry ALL abortion.

Comment: I agree.  However, what do you do when one must make a choice between abortion and the life of the mother?  One cannot be hard and fast here but some of these choices are very difficult.  Some simply say that one should never abort but some must make difficult decisions especially when the chances of survival of the unborn are low.  Or should we let nature take its course?  Such an attitude would prevent us from catching people who fall.

Comment: Similar choices are made in accidents when one can only save one not two people.  I have seen other cases where if there is no abortion, neither mother nor baby will survive.

Comment: I think it is very simple actually. Do not murder. If you are faced with the "choice" of the mother or the child (which is virtually non-existent with modern medicine) you don't make the choice. You do what is in your ability to save both. That's not the same as letting nature take it's course, but instead is doing what you know to be right based on God's revealed word and trust God that his will be done. I look to David in this situation, all he could do was pray to God in the hope that his child might live. When the child died David continued to trust in the faithfulness of God.

Comment: Essentially I would say you're unintentionally making a category error.

Comment: I think you are correct but the law still defines an abort as an abortion.  nevertheless, I believe we agree.

Comment: Yes it seems so. But in this case I believe despite the law's definitions, the Bible is clear that this is murder.

Comment: I would briefly also like to dispute that GOD is ONLY the judge of spiritual sin. God ordains that his justice for crimes is punished by the civil magistrate, but that doesn't remove him as "the ultimate magistrate" in civil issues. That's like saying "Keep God out of government." No need to reply I just wanted to say that.